# Index out of range SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I have declared a struct, which should have an id and a litereal

```
struct Lit: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id      : Int
    var literal : String
}
```

Here is my code where I decode a JSON file into a list:
The JSON file contains 3 items

```
[{"id":0,"literal":"arda"},{"id":0,"literal":"mecho"},{"id":0,"literal":"dossi"}]
```

```
class Literal: ObservableObject {

  @Published var lit = [Lit]()

  init() {
    loadLiteral()
  }
  func loadLiteral(){

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://biobeehive.com/Dossi.json") else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url ) { (data,_,_) in
      guard let data = data else {return}

      let pokemon200 = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Lit].self, from: data)

      DispatchQueue.main.async  {
        self.lit  = pokemon200
        print("\(self.lit[0].literal)")
      }
    }.resume()

  }
}
```

Bellow, I want to print the literal at index 0, it should print "arda", but instead of that I get an error.( Fatal error: Index out of range: file ), even though I see that all the 3 items exist and have been passed.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var literal = Literal()

  var body: some View {

    VStack {

      Text("\(literal.lit.count)")   // Output is 3
      Text("\(literal.lit[0].literal)") //Crashing here

    }
}
```

Would you please tell me how to fix that?

Comment: The reason it crushes is because the `lit` array is empty before the network request with the JSON data completes. So, the first time the view renders, it attempts to access `[0]` of an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

reason: the async loading takes some time and the data is not loaded when view appears, so it crashes because there is no data at all.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var literal = Literal()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            if literal.lit.count > 0 {
                Text("\(literal.lit.count)")   // Output is 3
                Text("\(literal.lit[0].literal)") //Crashing here
            } else {
                Text("still loading...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot. My confusion was because I was loading 3 and therefore I was thinking that it has been already loaded.